# Will I will be able to sit and watch the movie?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Recently I went to the theater. When I came to buy my $3$ tickets (two friends and I), the machine tells me that there is $18$ seats out of $300$ ($15$ rows of $20$ seats).

> What is the probability that remains 3 empty seats side-by-side?

Comment: The last condition may make the problem too difficult to solve except by a simulation. The condition is also somewhat unspecific. Does it mean people come in couples?

Comment: Oops, I just assumed that it means that we never watch the movie separated. Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would it be easier if we assumed that everyone comes accompanied by one person (average)?

Comment: The analysis would be very difficult. Assume couples. If they choose adjacent seats at random, there will be usually many gaps of $1$, and $3$ in a row has very low probability. But one could at best hope for estimates.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok. If I just want to know if I can get 3 seats side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

Probability we do not get to sit=prob(each row has exactly 1 seat)+prob(each row has at most 2 seats).

Each seat can be placed in any of the 15 rows, i.e, in 15 ways. Hence, the 15 seats can be distributed in a total of (15x15x15....15)=$15^{15}$ ways. Each row having one seat is only one of all those different distributions. Hence,
Prob(each row has exactly 1 seat)=$\frac{1}{15^{15}}$

prob(each row has at most 2 seats)=prob(13rows have 1 seat each, and another one has 2 seats)=$\frac{{15\choose13} .2}{15^{15}}$.

(Note that the 13 rows which have 1 seat can be chosen in ${15\choose13}$ ways, and from the other 2 rows, the row with 2 seats can be chosen in 2 ways.)

Probability we do not get to sit=$\frac{1}{15^{15}}$+$\frac{{15\choose13} .2}{15^{15}}$.

Comment: Your solution work only if we assumend there have $15$ seats out.